# Making sure I'm writing to memory I own in C

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Person
{
    unsigned long age;
    char name[20];
};

struct Array
{
    struct Person someone;
    unsigned long used;
    unsigned long size;
};

int main()
{
    //pointer to array of structs
    struct Array** city;
    //creating heap for one struct Array
    struct Array* people=malloc(sizeof(struct Array));
    city=&people;

    //initalizing a person
    struct Person Rob;
    Rob.age=5;
    strcpy(Rob.name,"Robert");

    //putting the Rob into the array
    people[0].someone=Rob;

    //prints Robert
    printf("%s\n",people[0].someone.name);
    //another struct
    struct Person Dave;
    Dave.age=19;
    strcpy(Dave.name,"Dave");
    //creating more space on the heap for people. 
    people=realloc(people,sizeof(struct Array)*2);
    //How do I know that this data is safe in memory from being overwritten? 
    people[1].someone=Dave;
    //prints Dave
    printf("%s\n",people[1].someone.name);
    //accessing memory on the heap I do not owe?
    people[5].someone=Rob;
    //prints "Robert" why is this okay? Am I potentially overwriting memory?
    printf("%s\n",people[5].someone.name);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I attempt to make a pointer to a dynamic array of structs, unsure if I succeeded in that part, but my main concern is I use malloc to create space on the heap for the array 'people.' Later in the code I create another struct Person and use realloc to create more space on the heap for 'people.' I then write to memory outside of what I thought I gave space for by doing 'people[5].someone=Rob;.' This still works as I have access to the value at that memory location. My question is why does this work? Am I potentially overwriting memory by writing to memory I did not specifically define for people? Am I actually using malloc and realloc correctly? As I did hear that there were ways of testing if they were successful in another post. I am new to C so if my assumptions or terminology is off please correct me.

Comment: Please tell me this is homework. There's no way anyone should be writing end user application code like this in C these days.

Comment: This is me practicing on my own/ self-teaching so bare with me. Ahhh yes forgot about freeing people, but that does not answer my question.

Comment: You're absolutely writing to memory you don't own. Sometimes, by luck, that memory exists and isn't being used for anything else, and stuff happens to work. Don't count on that, though.

Comment: "why does this work" you're invoking *undefined behavior*. Worse, you're equating *observed behavior* with *defined behavior*. Your `people[5].someone=Rob;` is outside the allocated memory region pointed to by `people`. as such your program is ill-formed, and any behavior it exhibits cannot be equated with any sort of definitive behavior. You were (un)lucky that it "worked" at all.

Comment: Thank you, I was just making sure. For more complicated pieces of code is there a way for me to know I'm only accessing memory I own? or to protect me from making a stupid mistake like this?

Comment: Rob, not within `C` itself, tools like Valgrind may help though. You just have to be very careful.

Comment: There are no boundaries checking in C and mostly C++, so you can always "shoot your leg". Knowledge is your best protection - the better you understand what you write (want to write) the better your code will be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an expert in C, not even a middle, most of the time I program in C#, so some mistakes might be there.

Modern operating systems have a special mechanism called the memory manager. Using that mechanism we can ask OS to give us some amount of memory. In Windows there's a special function for that - VirtualAlloc. It's a really powerful function, you can read more about it on MSDN.

It works really great and gives us all the memory we require but there's a little problem - it gives us the whole physical pages (4KB). Well, actually that is not a big problem, you can use this memory in the same way as if it was allocated using malloc. There'll be no error.

But it is a problem because if we, for example, allocate a 10 byte chunk using VirtualAlloc, it will actually give us 4096 byte chunk as the memory size is rounded up to the page size boundary. So VirtualAlloc allocate a 4KB memory chunk, but we actually use only 10 bytes of it. The rest 4086 are "gone". If we create the second 10 byte array, VirtualAlloc will give us another 4096 byte chunk, so two 10 byte arrays will actually take 8KB of RAM.

To solve this problem, every C program uses `malloc` function, which is a part of the C runtime library. It allocates some space using VirtualAlloc and returns pointers to the parts of it. For example let's return to our previous arrays. If we allocate 10 byte array using malloc, the runtime library will call VirtualAlloc to allocate some space, and malloc will return pointer to the beginning of it. But if we allocate 10 byte array for the second time, malloc won't use VirtualAlloc. Instead, it will use the already allocated page, I mean the free space of it. After allocation of the first array, we got 4086 bytes of unused space in our memory chunk. So malloc will use this space wisely. In this case (for the second array) it will return pointer to `"address of chunk" + 10` (that's a memory address).

Now we can allocate about 400 "ten byte arrays" and they will take only 4096 bytes if we use malloc. Naive way using VirtualAlloc would take `400 * 4096 bytes = 1600KB`, that's a rather big figure in comparison to 4096 bytes using malloc.

There's another reason - performance, as VirtualAlloc is a really expensive operation. However, malloc will do some pointer math if you have free space in the allocated chunks, but if you don't have any free allocated space, it will call VirtualAlloc. Actually it's much more complicated than I say, but I think that would be enough to explain the cause.

Okay, let's return to the question. You allocate the memory for the `Array` array. Let's calculate it's size: `sizeof(Person) = sizeof(long) + sizeof(char[20]) = 4 + 20 = 24 bytes`; `sizeof(Array) = sizeof(Person) + 2 * sizeof(long) = 24 + 8 = 32 bytes`. The array of 2 elements will take 32 * 2 = 64 bytes. So, as I said before, malloc will call VirtualAlloc to allocate some memory, and it will return a 4096 bytes page. So, for example let's assume that the address of the chunk's beginning is 0. Application can modify any byte from 0 to 4096 as we allocated the page and we won't get any pagefault. What is an array indexation `array[n]`? It's just summation of the array's base and the offset calculated as `array + n * sizeof(*array)`. In case of `person[5]` it will be `0 + sizeof(Array) * 5 = 0 + 5 * 64 = 320 bytes`. Gotcha! We're still in the chunk's boundary, I mean we access the existing physical page. A pagefault would happen if we tried to access an unexisting virtual page, but in our case it exists at address 320 (from 0 to 4096 as we assumed). It's dangerous to access unallocated space as it can lead to lots of unknown consequences, but we can actually do it!

That's why you don't get any `Access Violation at ****`. But it's actually MUCH WORSE. Because if you for example try accessing the zero pointer you will get a pagefault and your app will just crash, therefore you WILL know the cause of the problem with a help of the debugger or something else. But if you overrun the buffer and you don't get any error, you will go crazy while looking for the problem's cause. Because it's REALLY HARD to find this kind of errors. And you can even be NOT AWARE of it. So NEVER OVERRUN THE BUFFER ALLOCATED IN THE HEAP. Actually Microsoft's C Runtime has a special "debug" version of malloc that can find these errors at runtime, but you need to compile application with "DEBUG" configuration. Also, there are some special thing like Valgrind, but I have a little experience in these stuff.

Well, I have written alot, sorry for my english, I'm still learning it. Hope it will help you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to understand in terms of memory. Thank you very much.

Comment: NOTE that even though your program has access to the memory (no SIGSEGV), it's not safe to write beyond what you've malloc()d/realloc()d - if the program does any other malloc()s, those out of range addresses may be in use for something else. Worst case, they are used for metadata within the C library, and overwriting could have spectacularly unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

First, never forget to free your memory.

```
// NEVER FORGET TO FREE YOUR MEMORY
free(people);
```

As for this part

```
//accessing memory on the heap I do not owe?
people[5].someone=Rob;
//prints "Robert" why is this okay? Am I potentially overwriting memory?
printf("%s\n",people[5].someone.name);
```

you are just being lucky (or unlucky in my opinion, since you don't see the logical mistake you are doing).

This is undefined behaviour, since you have two cells, but you access a 6th one, you go out of bounds.